# Populate listview with audio files from server

Tags: android, listview, server

In my android application I am required to fetch audio files from my server into a listview. I was able to do something similar using the sd card but I am completely lost on how to do it using a server. How would I be able to fecth audio from a server and place it into a listview ? I already know how to do this with images but I'm unable with audio.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify. When you say "I already know how to do this with images..." do you mean you can get images from the server or is that from the SD card?

Comment: I meant I am able to fetch images from server and place them into a listview but I am unable to do this with audio

Comment: You obviously can't "display" audio in a `ListView` you're going to have to get a list of audio filenames and display those.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant sorry for the misunderstanding. I would like to achieve something like soundclouds listview of music files when streaming music

Comment: Well if you're able to do it with images (which obviously means getting a list of image file URLs from the server) why can't you simply use the same sort of code for music file names / URLs ?

Comment: With the images I was using lazy loading into listview with the audio I am unsure of what you are saying. Should I try store the details such as the URL and file name into the database and echo them back to the application?

Comment: Okay so obviously you need to make HTTP request to server (possibly with some parameters) and then the server will give you the response data (probably XML or JSON type) which you can parse and then put it your listview by using custom adapter.